# Ashes Of The Singularity Escalation Can't start because api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-2-0.dll is missing

Tags: windows-7, windows, gaming, dll

I played and beat all the missions in Ashes Escalation on a previous version (2.1.1.4 I think) and the game ran perfectly, and now I go and update my game (GOG version) to 2.21.26459 and I get "api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-2-0.dll" is missing from your computer and the game won't start.  I installed the game with the full installer (GOG doesn't provide patches, really annoying), it gave me this error, then I tried running the installer again and same issue.  Restarted my computer, same issue.  I'm running Windows 7.

I tried launching the game with the Ashes exe and the Ashes DX11 and DX12 executables.  Same errors (I know DX12 won't work on windows 7, but I tried it just in case).   I ran the game perfectly before the updates.

The message is "the program can't start because api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-2-0.dll is missing from your computer"

Comment: this file is part of Win8, but not Windows 7.looks like the developers now use a function that is not available in windows 7. ask their support

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I already posted on their forums but they didn't reply.  Are you guys saying that I can't play this game under windows 7 anymore?  Rmhound, why do i need to register the dll.  Shouldn't this be done automatically by Visual C++ or something during it's install?

Comment: I didn't try it yet.  Could this mess something up if i try to register it?  I have the x64 and x86 version of VC++ 2017, 2013 and other before it.  2015 doesn't install because it says I have a newer version (which I do, 2017).

Comment: the VC++ installers don't install this file . this file is part of Windows 8

Comment: But I have windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else wondering, this was an issue with the game install as I suspected.  They included unnecessary dlls that had to be deleted to fix the issue.

Thanks for everyone's help :)